# Python 3.5 "cannot find vcvarsall.bat"

Tags: python, windows, python-3.5

For two weeks now, I've been trying to install Python docx on Python 3.5 with Windows 7, and can't get beyond the "unable to find vcvarsall.bat" error. I have downloaded and installed Visual Studios 14.0, but so far I haven't been able to fix this.

I have found a few answers here in Stack Overflow regarding this issue, but either I have try them and they don't work, or they are written in technical jargon that is beyond my grasp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem.  You need to install visual studio 2015 (the community version is free).

When you are going through the setup, at some point you will be able to choose optional features.  There has been a change in the newer version, and the c++ compiler is now an optional feature, and your error message is because that is missing.  You will need to choose to add the c++ compiler (under languages, just select all the c++ options), and that should fix your problem.  If it is already installed, you can probably just run the installer again, and select to modify the installation.  It may take a while to install - it took forever on my system.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to have worked fine :) Now, however, it says it can't find libxml2, which apparently can't be found using pip.

Comment: You should be able to find windows binaries of libxml that you can download.  Start [here](http://www.xmlsoft.org/) and follow the download links.  If you put them (the dll files) anywhere in your path, that should fix that problem.